# Is it possible to get the current system time dynamically on Angular without using a backend service?

Tags: angular, linux

As the title says, I want the current system time.
I know that using `Date()` can give me the current time, but that isn't necessarily the system time so it doesn't help.

I know I can use http request for getting the system time from some backend service, but the problem is that I want the system time to be updated dynamically (if system time changes - I expect my web page to change the time even if I don't refresh the page).
So if there's a way to achieve this using angular only - it will be much easier.

Is it possible to do so?

Example:
I'm using Linux machine, and now I set the current date to be 1 Feb 2022, 03:12:20  like this:

```
sudo date -s "1 FEB 2022 03:12:20"
```

So now I expect my web page to display the same date and time - 1 FEB 2022 03:12:20

Answer (score 1):

you can use a rxjs operator and map

```
date$=timer(0,1000).pipe(map(_=>new Date()))
{{date$|async}}
```

But this only give you the date in the client. If you want the date in server you need make a call to the server to correct

So you can has some like

```
  incr:number=0;
  date$=timer(0,1000).pipe(
    switchMap((i:number)=>{
      if (i%10==0)  //you can indicate here when you want "check"
                    //the date in server,e.g. each 10 seconds
      {
        return this.service.getDate().pipe(tap(x=>{
        this.incr=x.getTime()-new Date().getTime()}))
        }
      return of(new Date(new Date().getTime()+this.incr))
  }))
```

Comment: But isn't there a performance problem to fetch the time from the server every few seconds?

Comment: use `if (i==0)` if only want to make one call to your server (or use the first approach) But be sure if it's critical -e.g. you are making a quiz and you want to control the "time" to response the quiz- you should call another time to your server to avoid the user change his "clock". You never can trust in the "date" from the client.

Comment: I actually want the time to be updated on my web app when time on the system (sever) changes, or no more than few seconds after - so your solution is good in that terms. But wouldn't it make performance problems?

Answer (score 0):

didn't test it, but `new Date()` should always give you the system time, meaning that you could just get `new Date()` every second.

[this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#beschreibung) roughly translates to:

> If no arguments are given, the constructor creates a date object with the date and time of the current system time zone

so the solution would be:

```js
document.setInterval(() => console.info(new Date()), 1000);
```

or maybe more angularly (using rxjs instead of vanilla)

```js
timer(1000).subscribe(() => console.info(new Date());
```